# How to get accompanying var value in a struct?

Tags: ios, swift

Still a beginner so not sure if this is possible, but I have parsed an XML and saved it as a struct like below. The XML has a number of entries with a months, eventdates, and holiday tags. I want to get the accompanying eventdate and holiday values if I check that I have the month value. How can I call the other values in the struct like this?

```
struct myEventDates {
var month = ""
var eventdate = ""
var holiday = ""
}
```

I have a collection view calendar that shows a month at a time. Whenever the month showing is the same as the month in the struct holding the xml data, I want to print all of the accompanying eventdates and holidays in a grouped tableview.

Here's what I've done so far.

```
//Mark: TableView Delegate/DataSource for Date and Holiday Names
class CalendarViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

 //Mark: Appended XMLParser data to this variable
 var myCalendarDatesStrut = [CalendarDates]()

//Mark: Want as many sections as there are xml entries, so checking to see if current month == month tag of entry in xml, and settings total count as numberOfSections
//This works
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
    let currentMonthShown = formatter.string(from: selectedDate)
    let monthsFromCalendarXML = myCalendarDatesStrut.map {$0.month}
    let eventsInThisMonthCount = monthsFromCalendarXML.filter{ $0 == currentMonthShown}.count
    return eventsInThisMonthCount
}

//Mark: Want header of each section to be the entrydate. I think the way to do this is to check if month shown in calendar == month in xml entry and if so, print the eventdates as headers, but I dont know how to get the accompanying event dates

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
    let currentMonthShown = formatter.string(from: selectedDate)
    let monthsFromCalendarXML = myCalendarDatesStrut.map {$0.month}

        if monthsFromCalendarXML.contains(currentMonthShown) {
            for each in myCalendarDatesStrut {
                print(each.eventdate, "each.eventdate") //this just prints all of the eventdates in the xml but I need it to only print the dates that have the same month.
    }}}
```

Comment: What part of this are you facing issues with?

Comment: I am not getting what issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand what you meant correctly, you can probably filter the array first before looping through it

```
for each in myCalendarDatesStrut.filter({ $0.month == currentMonthShown }) {
    print(each.eventdate, "\(each.eventdate)")
}
```

or while looping through it

```
for each in myCalendarDatesStrut {
    if each.month == currentMonthShown {
        print(each.eventdate, "\(each.eventdate)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about filter entirely. I have a followup question about tableview's titleForHeader method and how to return multiple values in this method. I can't set let eachEventDate = each.eventdate and then return eachEventDate for the method. Why is this? The method wants a string and return eachEventDate is a string